# Failed to Add custom attributes - need to fix

Tags: c#, .net, comobject, dsofile

I'm using `DSOFile` to write custom attributes to a file by using the following code:

```
DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties file = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties(); 
file.Open(@"C:\More_info.docx",false,DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
```

> But it gives me the following error while running the code:
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in batchFile.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass' to interface type
>   'DSOFile._OleDocumentProperties'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{58968145-CF01-4341-995F-2EE093F6ABA3}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Then change the type of `file` as `dynamic` it executed the line but not able to add or view the properties associated with the file, all properties are showing **The function evaluation requires all threads to run.** 
That is the code will look like this:

```
dynamic myFile = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
file.Open(@"C:\More_info.docx",false,DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
```

Here is the image what happens when i watch the variable while debugging:

[image]

What i'm doing wrong? any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you found a solution? I have the same problems...